# Issue related to Js/React arrays

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, reactjs, web

I'm creating an array of `indexes` in which I'm appending values(this will later be used in a map function).

```
let indexes = [];
export default function SortTiles() {

    let num = info.num_tiles;
    for (let i = 10; i < num+10; i++) {
        indexes = [...indexes, i];
    }
    console.log(indexes);
    console.log("UWU")

    return(
        <div id={"sort-tiles"}>
            {/*{indexes.map(makeTiles)}*/}
        </div>
    )
}
```

But when I'm trying to console.log my array this is the output I'm getting:
[The output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUkFk.png)
The output is being printed twice and the numbers in the array are also duplicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what are you trying to achieve but this is not the proper way to handle arrays or any data in react component.

Try this may be this will help you or might fix your problem.

```
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

export default function SortTiles() {

  const [indexes, setIndexes] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    let num = 20;
    let indexArr = []
    for (let i = 10; i < num+10; i++) {
      indexArr = [...indexArr, i];
    }
    setIndexes(indexArr);
  }, [])


return(
    <div id={"sort-tiles"}>
        {indexes.map((ind) => (<div>{ind}</div>))}
    </div>
)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The array is printed twice most likely because you are in [strict mode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html), which double renders components to help catch bugs.

Lucky for you, it helped you catch one! The values are duplicated because the `indexes` variable is declared outside the function. Since you never reset it to an empty value, every re-render will just continue adding indexes. Try initializing it inside the function.